Could not load NIB in bundle, DropDownCell via pod Dropdown
I am facing issue with a pod. The pods folder contains the files and the XIB file in Resources folder too yet when I try to use the dropdown object I am getting error.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/ABC.app> (loaded)' with name 'DropDownCell''

Accessing from Code
private var dropDown = DropDown()

PODFILE
platform :ios, '12.0'

project ‘Sample’, 'ReleaseStore' => :release

inhibit_all_warnings!
use_modular_headers!

target ‘M’yTarget do
    pod 'DropDown'
end


post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0' # update target to project target

            if config.name == 'Debug' # update compilation mode to match main project build settings
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE'] = 'singlefile'
            else
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE'] = 'wholemodule'
            end
        end
    end
end

